# Resizing and Collapsing label in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label, resize

first time poster, sorry if something isn't as it should be.

I'm new to Winforms and am trying to build a simple application that will display multiple features of an item (like Size, Composition, etc.). Each Characteristic has a Name, can have a Descritpion, and some can have sub-characteristics (having also a name and sometimes a descritpion).

I want to display them one under the other, with the Name of the feature on a blue background that span the whole width of the container, with the description underneath. The name will be (or have) a button (or similar) that when clicked collapse or expand the description. This must be created at run time because I don't know how many feature an object has until the user generate it.

The issues I'm running in are that either I can't span the blue background the whole width of the container (if using a FlowLayoutPanel), or I have some issue with the Description text being not the right size (either it wraps but is too big, or it doesn't wrap and then I can't see the whole text).

Some things are fixed, mainly the number of main sections (like Size, Composition, Weather, etc.), so I can prepare the skeleton  before runtime.
[The closest i've been to making it work gives this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIXVI.png) This issue here is that the height of the Panel which the description label is embded in is fixed, and if I put in in Autosize, the text don't show (probably because the label is in Fill dock style). [Just as information, this is what it looks like when collapsed (this is indeed what I'm looking for)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og7iC.png)

I know some library exists with collapsible panels, but I'd rather try to make it work without external libraries. Thanks in advance for any help !

This is the code that produces the results in the screenshots :

```
        Panel SizeDescrPanel = new Panel();
        SizeDescrPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        //SizeDescrPanel.AutoSize = true;
        SizeDescrPanel.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        SizeDescrPanel.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
        SizePanel.Controls.Add(SizeDescrPanel);

        Label SizeDescrLbl = new Label();
        SizeDescrLbl.Text = Lorem;
        SizeDescrLbl.AutoSize = false;
        SizeDescrLbl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        SizeDescrLbl.BackColor = Color.BurlyWood;
        SizeDescrPanel.Controls.Add(SizeDescrLbl);

        /*using(Graphics g = CreateGraphics())
        {
            SizeF size = g.MeasureString(SizeDescrLbl.Text, SizeDescrLbl.Font, SizePanel.Width);
            SizeDescrPanel.Height = (int) Math.Ceiling(size.Height);
        }*/

        Panel SizeNamePanel = new Panel();
        SizeNamePanel.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        SizeNamePanel.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
        SizeNamePanel.AutoSize = true;
        SizePanel.Controls.Add(SizeNamePanel);

        Button SizeNameBtn = new Button();
        SizeNameBtn.Text = "<Size Name> ..." + SizeDescrLbl.Height;
        SizeNameBtn.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        SizeNameBtn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        SizeNameBtn.AutoSize = true;
        SizeNamePanel.Controls.Add(SizeNameBtn);

        SizeNameBtn.Click += delegate { HideShowPanel(SizeDescrPanel); };
```

It,s a test project, so later I'll put that in different methods. What isn't shown here :

- I have a main panel set to Fill containing everything.
- The text "SIZE" is a label set to Top
- Under it is another Panel (SizePanel) that is set to Top and Autosize is at True. This is the Panel inside which I'm puttin my size name and my size description. If I had a subfeature, it would be included (ideally) inside descritpion with the same configuration (button expanding/collapsing the descritpion of the SubFeature)

Comment: You can get the size needed to display a text (at a given font size and a width) with one of the measuretext and/or measurestring functions. We can't say what goes wrong without seeing at least some of your code, though..

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! As shown in the code I added, I tried using the MeasureString function, and it kinda worked, but only if I'm not resizing the window. Anyway to try to use that and I guess fire it each time the window is resized ?

Comment: It sounds like you don't want `SizeNameBtn.AutoSize = true;` since you want to span the entire width.  It sounds like you do want `SizeDescrLbl.AutoSize = true;`.  Try setting the `MaximumSize.Width` property to get the right word wrap.

Comment: Yes, if a Resize changes the target width you will need to adapt the sizes and repeat the measurement..

Comment: Why don't you build an UserControl that contains all the logic needed to expand/collapse a child Control? You just add a single UserControl for each Item, problem solved. -- Note that you can set the MinimumSize / MaximumSize of a Label that has `AutoSize = true`, set to the ClientSize of it's Container, eventually. Also, you can set these Properties as, e.g., `[Label].MinimumSize = new Size(200, 0)`, which limits the Width, but not the Height, so the Control will expand only downwards when the maximum Width of 200px is reached.

Comment: But limiting the maximum size will encounter the same issues as using the Measurestring function, won't it ? meaning, if I set it to my container size, and then the user resize the window, I'll have to change that maximum size ?

Comment: Of course. The Label's AutoSize functionality, as defined by the default LayouEngine, doesn't respect either Anchors or any container's bounds, only the Maximum/MinimumSize. So, if the Container is resized, you redefine the Maximum/MinimumSize accordingly. The measure of the Text is already performed by the AutoSize feature, it's not necessary to repeat it in your own code. Just restrict its bounds in a way that the LayoutEngine can understand/use. Or, build your own LayoutEngine and replace the default.

Comment: Btw, in a previous comment, I should have probably written `[Label].MaximumSize = new Size(200, 0);` The `MaximumSize` property is more relevant here. But, you may also want to use `MinimumSize`, so a Label won't shrink to a little square if there's no text. You may want to only shrink its Height, not its Width (thus a Container Panel set to AutoSize will also shrink accordingly). A UserControl can also auto-size itself to fit its content's overall bounds. So does a FlowLayoutPanel...

Comment: Hey, great thanks for all the answers, that works perfectly ! I didn't built an UserControl for the expand logic, all I do is just set the visibility of the DescriptionLabel  to false and since its container is set to autosize, it seems to shrink as desired.

I'm also gonna put all tthe Descriptions Label in a list, that way I can just iterate over said list on window resize in order to resize them all.